# Nonsmoothable 4-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, 4-manifolds

Does there exist a closed connected nonsmoothable 4-manifold $M$ such that:

1. $\kappa(M)=0$ ([Kirby-Siebenmann invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirby%E2%80%93Siebenmann_class) vanishes, hence, there is no "classical" obstruction to smoothability) and
2. $M$ is spin and has zero signature?

It follows from Freedman's theorem that there are no simply-connected manifolds with these properties (since every such manifold would be homeomorphic to the connected sum of several copies of $S^2\times S^2$ and, hence, smoothable). However, I do not even know the answer in the case of 4-manifolds with finite fundamental groups. The question itself came from my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115222/is-every-compact-n-manifold-that-immerses-in-mathbbrn1-smoothable/4116464#4116464).

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia 4-manifold page?  It gives a little extra information on your question.

Comment: @RyanBudney: I decided to check just in case and did not find anything that would shed a light on my question (beyond what I wrote in the post). What do you have in mind? Of course, Freedman's result goes beyond the simply connected case, which allowes one to prove smoothability for special fundamental groups. But, as I said, even the finite group case is unclear to me. Is it clear to you?

Comment: In the case of finite fundamental group, the universal cover is homeomorphic to $k(S^2\times S^2)$ for some $k \geq 0$. When $k = 0$, there are no orientable quotients. If I have understood the introduction to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04572) correctly, there are orientable quotients if $k = 1$, but they don't satisfy your criteria.

Comment: Not an answer but two minor comments. Firstly: if $M^4$ is closed and spin, then $ks(M)=\sigma(M)/8$ mod $2$ so your second condition implies your first. Secondly: since $M$ is indefinite, Donaldson's theorem won't apply so presumably (?) a positive answer would go through HF or SW invariants?

Comment: @AnthonyConway: Yes, you are right on both.